# Please help identify thing wired into my home alarm

Tags: wiring, security, data-wiring, low-voltage, alarm

Wired into my alarm panel per the enclosed photo is a small black-wrapped device wired to the 12V+, - & Earth.

What might this be for - voltage stabilisation, noise reduction, ...?

Grateful for your assistance before I take the often regrettable step of opening it up.

[image: Alarm Panel]

Comment: Can you get us close-ups of it?

Comment: It looks a bit like a jack socket.  Maybe to power a test connection.  As already suggested - try for a close-up.

Comment: If there is only the 3wires (red black green) attached to it, then it must be some type of transient voltage suppressor.    Just to be clear, the yellow blue pair pictured is running behind the device and not connected to it? Is that correct?

Comment: "Often"? "Opening it up"? "Regrettable"? It sounds like you are a tinkerer who has a habit, need or compulsion to disassemble items of curiosity, and that often doesn't go well. You might want to get that looked at.  If the goal is learnng, there are far more efficient (and less destructive) ways to learn, this being one of them, so awesome.    Essential house utilities are untouchable because of impact on mortgage (the house is collateral) and insurance (priced based on the alarm system working, fraud to remove it).

Comment: I'm not a fan of how it's fetching ground from the mains side of the transformer.  A transformer should isolate, and this defeats the isolation.   If it's trying to surge suppress to ground, it should surge suppress to a ground that is relevant to the low voltage alarm system, not a ground from a different isolated system.

Comment: @Harper - that is *completely* legitimate. The output of the transformer is still isolated from ground.

Comment: Yes, the yellow/blue pair are not part of it. It does not have a jack connection. I'll post a closer photo from a different angle.